# Form View Issues

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I recently upgraded Office from 2010 to 2013. I am creating a database from scratch and the interface is different.

When I open a Form that I've created it appears to size to my screen even though under Design View I made the size of my form much smaller. Is there a setting that I am missing somewhere?

Also when I click on a button that is supposed to open a new form and close the current open form, the form I would like to open is opened in a new tab and the old form remains. The VBA used for this procedure is simple :

```
Sub ViewCollection_bt_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "CollectionView"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Main Menu"
End Sub
```

I re-saved my database with .accdr extension to see if it would make a difference with both of these issues but no go.

Anyone have any tips for both of these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve both of my issues by going to Options --> Current Database --> Document Window Options and selecting Overlapping Windows.